# Increase size of a Wine window

Tags: wine

(For 16.04 with Unity)

I have several old games that I play using Wine and the NVIDIA proprietary driver. I want to play them windowed, but my monitor uses a 4K resolution and some of these games can't go higher than 800x600, so the window on my desktop is very tiny. I don't want to play fullscreen. Is there a way to force Wine to occupy more pixels on my screen without some hackery to increase the game's resolution?

I have already tried winecfg -> Graphics -> Emulate a Virtual Desktop and increasing the number, but when the game starts the window sizes back to 800x600 again.

Comment: Old games may not support higher resolutions. If so, there's nothing you can do in Wine or even native Windows in the same machine.